# What is "useragent" in codeigniter email library's configuration?

Tags: email, codeigniter, user-agent

I can see that the codeigniter's email library's `useragent` is changeable as the document says.

But what is really the `useragent` and what does it do for us?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the email library's case, but in most cases the useragent is the identifier of what the user "used" to make a request in the way of the browser type/version, OS type/version, etc.

This information is commonly used or contained cookies.

Here are examples of useragents:

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:50

Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.3; en-au; GT-I9100 Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.12011-10-16 20:22:55

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)2011-10-16 20:22:33

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.02011-10-16 20:21:42

Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.12011-10-16 20:21:13

Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9800; en) AppleWebKit/534.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.0.337 Mobile Safari/534.1+2011-10-16 20:21:10

Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)2011-10-16 20:21:07

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:21:05

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) rekonq Safari/534.342011-10-16 20:21:01

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; GTB6; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)2011-10-16 20:20:48

BlackBerry8300/4.2.2 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 VendorID/107 UP.Link/6.2.3.15.02011-10-16 20:20:17
IE 7 ? Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)2011-10-16 20:20:09

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110920 Firefox/3.6.23 SearchToolbar/1.22011-10-16 20:20:07

Comment: Thank you. But I need to get more info about the `useragent` in the special case of email. I don't know the relation of `useragent` with sending email and so on. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The same thing I mentioned above, but the client program used to send the mail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_user_agent